# Bioshock - research camera status

Tags: bioshock

I'm replaying Bioshock for the first time in a long time. I seem to remember that there was a shortcut key to press in order to get status on research camera progress - maybe even see the pictures. I can't find this key or even confirm that it exists.

I am playing on a PC through Steam, if it matters.

What is this key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **can't** get the status on research progress in BioShock. I couldn't find an official statement but a couple of postings in forums. Here are two of them:

- [2k Forum](https://forums.2k.com/showthread.php?20925-Is-there-a-way-to-show-research-progress-in-the-game)
- [Gamefaqs](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/931330-bioshock/53523695)

In BioShock 2 it is possible to get the research progress but not in BioShock 1.

Comment: Thanks. I must have been thinking of Bioshock 2.